# Java Crop all Images in Folder

Tags: java, cmd, imagemagick

Working on Java code to crop all images in folder using java code, processbuilder, This code is working but, its only doing for first file, other files not doing..Please help me!! Thanks!!

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class test1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            File folder = new File("Map_Image");
            File[] BFFile = folder.listFiles();

            String full_path = null;
            String new_path = null;

             for (File file : BFFile) {

                 String str = file.getName(); 
                 System.out.println("Image File:- " + str);


                 full_path = file.getAbsolutePath();


                 new_path = folder + "\\" + "new_" + str;
                 System.out.println("New Image Files:- " + new_path);

             try {
                 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\\convert.exe", "-crop", "512x512+0-20", full_path, new_path);
                 Process p = pb.start();
                 p.waitFor();
             } catch(Exception error1) {
                error1.printStackTrace();
             }

             }

        } catch(Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Code it working but, it's only doing for first files its not doing for other files.. 
Output:

```
Image File:- address_map.jpg
New Image Files:- Map_Image\new_address_map.jpg
Image File:- Michael Couse_200857860.jpg
New Image Files:- Map_Image\new_Michael Couse_200857860.jpg
```

ProcessBuilder only running one time, its not running for others files..
Please help me!!
Thanks in Advanced!!

Comment: you need a recursive solution (*I'm assuming those other files live in subdirectories?*)

Comment: nope all files in same folder not in subfolders.. I don't know why only running for first file.. Please help me thanks!!

Comment: What does `p.waitFor();` return the first time?

Comment: @user3187463, the easiest way to troubleshoot this is to use a debugger.

Comment: yap..but It didn't give me any error, it just working for first time.. don't know why please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: I tried debugger, but still no error..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `listFiles` is quite buggy (especially with unicode names). What you can use is:

```
try (DirectoryStream ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(folder)) 
{
    for (Path file : ds) {
    // Your code goes here
    }
} 
catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That is not to say it will certainly fix your issue, but it's worth a try.